# "Tears in rain" monologue in Latin

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, translation-check

I've just read a Latin translation of the famous ["Tears in rain" speech](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tears_in_rain_monologue) in the Blade Runner film. See its source in: [I've seen things...](https://forum.unilang.org/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=41341)

"I've seen things you people wouldn't believe. Attack ships on fire off the shoulder of Orion. I watched C-beams glitter in the dark near the Tannhäuser Gate. All those moments will be lost in time, like tears in rain. Time to die".

> Vidi res quas fieri posse haud scio an nemo vestrum credat,
>   bellicas naves inflammatas iuxta Orionis umerum,
>   conspexi C radios in tenebris fulgere propter Tanhûseri portam.
>   Quae omnia procedente peribunt tempore
>   tamquam lacrimae in pluvia.
>   Tempus est mori.

In particular, the last sentence caught my attention. What about *Nunc est moriendum* on the basis of Horatius: [Nunc est bibendum](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/10809/nunc-est-bibendum-gerund-or-gerundive)? Could you please give your opinion on this sentence and on the rest of the Latin translation above as well? Alternative translations are welcome!

Comment: The derivation of "Now one must drink" (which appears to be the most apposite translation) was covered in "Nunc Est Bibendum". Analogously: "Now one must die"--more dramatic than "time to die"!

Comment: Ok. So, in order to avoid the possible "dramatic" effect you mention (although I understand the context here is quite dramatic, isn't it?), perhaps _(Iam) tempus est moriendi_ is better for you.

Comment: Think that "Nunc est moriendum" hits the nail-on-the-head! Working analogously can produce excellent results: Joonas worked analogously on "Cariotae cum Ficis Certandum Habent"; cnread, when he adapted Cicero's "quod male cecidit" (what has fallen [turned out] badly) to give "res bene cadent" (things will turn out well) on Q: "....Everything Will Be Well".