# I am looking for the Latin translation for 'these are the good times' As in enjoy right now and live in the moment. can anyone help?

Tags: classical-latin

I am looking for the Latin translation for 'these are the good times'  As in enjoy right now and live in the moment. can anyone help?

Comment: would 'hi prospera' cover this phrase?

Comment: "Carpe diem" pretty exactly covers your gloss of the intended phrase

Comment: @brianpck I agree that that's the best choice. Can you write it up into an answer? It doesn't have to be long, as further details can be found online once you know the phrase.

Comment: thank you for your comments.  i agree about Carpe Diem but it is a well used phrase and I was hoping to offer something a little different.

Answer (score 2):

You could go biblical with your translation: "meum calix meus inebrians." A common translation is "my cup is overflowing." Literally, it means "my chalice is intoxicating me." I think the famousness of this phrase means its metaphorical meaning will be appreciated over the literal reading.

This is from Psalm 23. http://bibleglot.com/pair/KJV/Vulgate/Ps.23/

Also, I hate to be a broken record (I've brought it up a lot) but: "Nunc est bibendum!" Now one must drink! This is such a great phrase from Horace which also captures your desire really well. There's a long thread talking about it here on the stack exchange:

[Nunc est bibendum: gerund or gerundive?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/10809/nunc-est-bibendum-gerund-or-gerundive)

Comment: Thank you for this alternative option. not one i had considered. It is great to get a different viewpoint on this.

Comment: @Nickimite: Ovid? Are you sure about that? The Q: "Nunc..." is one of the best that's ever been asked, on the site.

Comment: Hehe. I meant Horace. Good looking out -- I fixed my answer.