# What type of purpose clause for specifying a substantive gerundive

Tags: grammar-choice, gerundive, purpose-clause

When using a substantive gerundive, what form would a specifying purpose clause take? For instance: "things to be used *for fighting*," I would use a gerundive (utenda) and then what? A dative present participle? An infinitive? Ut + subjunctive? Is there an idiomatic way of doing this, or other preferred solution?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There are two types of dedicated purpose clauses known to grammarians: *ut/ne* clauses and relative clauses. I think the latter are ideally suited for the situation you describe. Let's take a somewhat clearer example: “The necessity of sending legates to sue for peace”:

> Necessitas legatorum mittendorum (vel legatos mittendi) qui pacem petant.

Note that the subjunctive makes all the difference: It turns an ordinary relative clause into a purpose clause.

Comment: As is well-known, in Classical Latin the gerundive construction (_legatorum mittendorum_) is preferred wrt the gerund one _legatos mittendi_, which is, as you point out, also accepted to some degree. However, when dealing with this gerund + object construction, what I do not understand is why the genitive construction (e.g., _legatos mittendi_) is more frequent than the **prepositional** one, which is practically absent in Latin (e.g. _in mittendo legatos / ad mittendum legatos_). Cf. https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/1144/when-can-the-gerund-take-an-object

Answer (score 3):

One construction in this direction is that used for various commissions:

> duoviri viis extra urbem purgandis
> tresviri aere argento auro flando feriundo
> quattuorviri viis in urbe purgandis
> decemviri sacris faciundis

When you have a magistrate for some purpose, using a dative gerundive is an idiomatic way to go about describing their task.

Comment: llmavirta: The second line: "tresviri with copper, silver & gold for blowing & beating", presumably the smelting process. Is "feriundo" from verb "ferio" = "to beat"; the dative gerundive from this would be "feriendo", wouldn't it?

Comment: @tony In the third and fourth conjugations the gerund and gerundive can use *-und-* instead of *-end-*, and this seems to be more common in older texts. You can replace *feriundo* and *faciundis* with *feriendo* and *faciendis* but you don't have to. // Those tresviri were responsible for minting coins.

Comment: Hello, me again. C.M. Weimer has deleted his answer so he will not entertain questions? He used "ad pugnandum" (gerund) = "for the purpose of fighting". If "ad" is used like this then it does not matter if the species is a gerund or a gerundive--they are indistinguishable e.g. "duas legiones in proelium misit ad hostes superandos." (gerundive); it could be either. Is this correct?

Comment: @tony Indeed, *ad* with either gerund or gerundive is one way to express purpose. But in your example *superandos* is a gerundive, not a gerund. The gerund would be *superandum* and also possible, but the gerundive is often preferred in cases like this.

Comment: For some (mysterious?) reason, the **prepositional** _ad_ + gerund + object construction _ad superandum hostes_ was not particularly accepted compared to the gerundive one _ad hostes superandos_. Cf . "the prohibition of using objects with gerunds is, for example, very strong in _**in**_ + ablative and _**ad**_ + accusative contexts across authors of different periods" (excerpted from my answer: https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/1144/when-can-the-gerund-take-an-object ).

Comment: @Mitomino Indeed, there are limitations to when a gerund can take an object. I purposely chose to simplify the matter in my comment. (I often find myself trying to balance between simplicity and accuracy when communicating science or anything similar.) The question you link to gives a lot more information for anyone wishing to dig deeper. I edited my previous comment slightly.

Answer (score 1):

Your example "things to be used for fighting" on the other hand I think would be something like *utilia ad pugnandum*, perhaps better *apta ad pugnandum*, or even *res ad pugnandum necessariae*.